# Is there a fast R function like rollapplyr with increasing window size?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo, sliding-window

I want to calculate a sum over a sliding window on grouped data.

As I would like to stick to official functions if possible I started with rollapplyr like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(zoo)  

data = data.frame(Count=seq(1,10,1),
                  group=c("A","B","A","A","B","B","B","B","A","A"))


window_size <- 3    

data_rolling <- data %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(Rolling_Count = rollapplyr(Count, width=window_size, FUN=sum, fill = NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

for the first entries which are smaller than width (in this case 3) it gets filled with NA as defined, but I would actually like to have the sum of the possible data there like this:

```
 Count group Rolling_Count expected_Result
 1     A            NA    1
 3     A            NA    4
 4     A            8     8
 9     A            16    16
10     A            23    23
 2     B            NA    2
 5     B            NA    7
 6     B            13    13
 7     B            18    18
 8     B            21    21
```

I know that I can replace the `width=window_size` with something like this:

```
c(rep(1:window_size,1),rep(window_size:window_size,(n()-window_size)))
```

to get what I want but this is really slow. In addition this approach would assume that n() is greater than window_size.

So: **Is there already an R/zoo function which can handle grouped data like above and in addition data with less than window_size entries and is faster to the above approach?**

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Replace the `NA`s with `cumsum(Count)` for each group. If speed is a concern consider `data.table` and `RcppRoll` packages.

Comment: Hi Marcus, thank you for your answer, but this is not exactly what I want - For group A I get two times 1 as a result and not 1,4.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I added the cumsum version in the original question.

Comment: What about `fill = 0`?

Comment: Or, `na.rm = TRUE` as additional parameter to `sum()`?

Comment: Hi Uwe, I do not see how these approaches would bring me closer to my goal. I do not have NA values in the summation and fill=0 will just fill it, well, with 0.

Comment: @StephanClaus I think the `fill` argument doesn't work that way. As I wrote, replace `NA`s with `cumsum(Count)` per group, you might add another `mutate` call for this. Or use Matt's answer.

Comment: @marcus: Thanks, but why did you change your first comment? You clearly suggested to use fill with cumsum(Count)...

Comment: Note `partial=TRUE` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution based on `data.table` and `RcppRoll` that should be much more performant.

It's not as clean as I would like -- there's actually a `partial` argument in `RcppRoll::roll_sum()` that hasn't been implemented yet that would theoretically solve this cleanly, but it doesn't seem like that will be worked anytime soon-- see [GH Issue #18](https://github.com/kevinushey/RcppRoll/issues/18) .

At any rate, until someone implements a rolling sum in R that allows what you need here, adding in a `cumsum` on the first `n - 1` rows seems to be a sensible solution.

```
library(data.table)
library(RcppRoll)

data = data.frame(Count=seq(1,10,1),
                  group=c("A","B","A","A","B","B","B","B","A","A"))

## Convert to a `data.table` by reference
setDT(data)
window_size <- 3    

## Add a counter row so that we can go back and fill in rows
## 1 & 2 of each group
data[,Group_RowNumber := seq_len(.N), keyby = .(group)]

## Do a rolling window -- this won't fill in the first 2 rows
data[,Rolling_Count := RcppRoll::roll_sum(Count,
                                          n = window_size,
                                          align = "right",
                                          fill = NA), keyby = .(group)]

## Go back and fill in the ones we missed
data[Group_RowNumber < window_size, Rolling_Count := cumsum(Count), by = .(group)]

data

#     Count group Group_RowNumber Rolling_Count
#  1:     1     A               1             1
#  2:     3     A               2             4
#  3:     4     A               3             8
#  4:     9     A               4            16
#  5:    10     A               5            23
#  6:     2     B               1             2
#  7:     5     B               2             7
#  8:     6     B               3            13
#  9:     7     B               4            18
# 10:     8     B               5            21
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, that works great (and super fast). I guess I have to look at the data.table library in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solutions, which is a little more base-R-ish and still should not lag behind in performance. It might be actually faster as it lacks all the features that *rolling* functions adds. We could replace `shift` function from `data.table` with base-R operation, then should be the fastest you can get in base R.
Note that this function will fail badly if some NAs will be present in input, also is more likely to suffer from floating point rounding error.

```r
data = data.frame(Count=seq(1,10,1),
                  group=c("A","B","A","A","B","B","B","B","A","A"))
window_size = 3

library(data.table)
setDT(data)
# base R fast rolling sum
bRfrs = function(x, n) {
  cumx = cumsum(x)
  cumx - shift(cumx, n, fill=0)
}
data[, .(Count, Rolling_Count=bRfrs(Count, window_size)), group]
#    group Count Rolling_Count
# 1:     A     1             1
# 2:     A     3             4
# 3:     A     4             8
# 4:     A     9            16
# 5:     A    10            23
# 6:     B     2             2
# 7:     B     5             7
# 8:     B     6            13
# 9:     B     7            18
#10:     B     8            21
```

In 1.12.4 release of data.table we are planning to add `frollsum` function already, then it will be another high performance option to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to utilise `data.table` and `collapse` we can achieve optimal performance by pre-computing the grouping structure, sorting the data by it if it already isn't, calculating a vector of window widths and passing that to `data.table::frollsum()`.

I have an implementation in my package: https://github.com/NicChr/timeplyr

```
window_size <- 3
data[, Rolling_Count := timeplyr::roll_sum(Count, g = group, window = window_size)][]
    Count group Group_RowNumber Rolling_Count
 1:     1     A               1             1
 2:     3     A               2             4
 3:     4     A               3             8
 4:     9     A               4            16
 5:    10     A               5            23
 6:     2     B               1             2
 7:     5     B               2             7
 8:     6     B               3            13
 9:     7     B               4            18
10:     8     B               5            21
```

#### Doing the same as above manually

```
# Groups
groups <- collapse::GRP(data, by = "group")
# Group sizes
group_sizes <- collapse::GRPN(groups, expand = F)

# Window vector
window_vec <- pmin(sequence(group_sizes), window_size)

# Sort data by groups
setkey(data, group)
# Rolling sum by group
data[, Rolling_Count := data.table::frollsum(Count, 
                                             n = window_vec,
                                             align = "right", adaptive = TRUE)]
# Sort back
data[collapse::greorder(seq_len(.N), g = groups)]
    Count group Rolling_Count
 1:     1     A             1
 2:     3     A             4
 3:     4     A             8
 4:     9     A            16
 5:    10     A            23
 6:     2     B             2
 7:     5     B             7
 8:     6     B            13
 9:     7     B            18
10:     8     B            21
```

#### Benchmark for lots of groups

```
library(bench)
df <- data.table(g = sample.int(10^4, 10^5, TRUE),
                 x = rnorm(10^5))
mark(e1 = df[, sum := frollsum(x, n = 7, align = "right", na.rm = FALSE), by = "g"]$sum,
     e2 = df[, sum := timeplyr::roll_sum(x, window = 7, g = get("g"), partial = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)]$sum)
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory     time      
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>     <list>    
1 e1         622.72ms 622.7ms      1.61  158.57MB     1.61     1     1      623ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
2 e2           8.09ms  11.1ms     89.6     4.02MB     0       45     0      502ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
# i 1 more variable: gc <list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few different approaches. (2), (4) and (5) assume that Count has no NA's (which is the case in the question's example data).

**1) rollapplyr/partial** Use `partial=TRUE` in `rollapplyr`:

```
data %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  mutate(Rolling_Count = 
    rollapplyr(Count, window_size, sum, fill = NA, partial = TRUE),
    .by = group)
```

**2) rollsumr/coalesce** or use `coalesce` with `rollsumr`

```
data %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  mutate(Rolling_Count = coalesce(
    rollsumr(Count, window_size, sum, fill = NA), 
    cumsum(Count)), .by = group)
```

**2a) rollsumr prepending zeros**  Here we prepend window_size-1 zeros or

```
data %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  mutate(Rolling_Count = 
       rollsumr(c(numeric(window_size-1), Count), window_size, sum), 
    .by = group)
```

**3) sql** Another possibility is to use SQL

```
library(sqldf)
library(magrittr)

data %>% {
  fn$sqldf("select
    *, 
    sum(Count) over 
      (partition by [group]
      order by rowid
      rows between `window_size` - 1 preceding and current row) as Rolling_Count
    from [.]"
) }
```

**4) diff/cumsum** We can also use `diff/cumsum` to get the result using only dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  mutate(Rolling_Count = window_size %>%
                         numeric %>%
                         c(Count) %>%
                         cumsum %>%
                         diff(window_size), .by = group)
```

**5) Base R** This uses only base R. It is similar to (4).

```
o <- order(data$group)
transform(data[o, ], Rolling_Count = ave(Count, group, FUN = \(x)
  window_size |>
  numeric() |>
  c(x) |>
  cumsum() |>
  diff(window_size)))
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use the partial argument that rollapplyr provides for this purpose

```
rollapplyr(Count,
 width=window_size,
 FUN=sum,
 fill = NA,
partial=TRUE)
```